# How too handle liquid flow in a tile based game?

Tags: c#, xna, tile

Just like the title says, I need to handle liquids in a tile based game.

**Info:** Each tile is 16xPixels and it has a WaterLevel(byte).
The water is supposed to average out with the other tiles near it, since each tile has a water level. But I can't seem to do it.

I want it to be like in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v9sH638nr0

But I just can't do it. Help?

```
if (WaterLevel > 0)
        {
            //Bottom
            if (Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X, (int)TileLocation.Y + 1].Collide == false && Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X, (int)TileLocation.Y + 1].WaterLevel != 255)
            {
                if ((int)Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X, (int)TileLocation.Y + 1].WaterLevel + (int)WaterLevel > 255)
                {
                    WaterLevel -= (byte)(255 - Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X, (int)TileLocation.Y + 1].WaterLevel);
                    Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X, (int)TileLocation.Y + 1].WaterLevel = 255;
                }
                else
                {
                    Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X, (int)TileLocation.Y + 1].WaterLevel += WaterLevel;
                    this.WaterLevel = 0;
                }
            }
            //Left or Right
            else
            {
                bool Left = Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X - 1, (int)TileLocation.Y].Collide;
                bool Right = Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X + 1, (int)TileLocation.Y].Collide;
                byte Divider = 1;
                int Average = WaterLevel;
                if (Left)
                {
                    Divider += 1;
                    Average += Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X - 1, (int)TileLocation.Y].WaterLevel;
                }
                if (Right)
                {
                    Divider += 1;
                    Average += Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X + 1, (int)TileLocation.Y].WaterLevel;
                }
                WaterLevel = (byte)(Average / Divider);
                Average /= Divider;
                Divider -= 1;
                if (Left)
                {
                    Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X - 1, (int)TileLocation.Y].WaterLevel = (byte)(Average / Divider);
                    Average /= Divider;
                    Divider -= 1;
                }
                if (Right)
                {
                    Program.Game.CurrentMap.Tiles[(int)TileLocation.X + 1, (int)TileLocation.Y].WaterLevel = (byte)(Average / Divider);
                    Average /= Divider;
                    Divider -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whats your current problems your running into?

Comment: I suggest looking for explanation of how it's actually done in terraria. There are some basic algorithms, shouldn't be difficult to understand.

Comment: There are no actual exceptions here, just the water doesn't flow to the lowest point like I want it to.

Comment: I checked Terraria, but the source is SOO messy, I don't want to get in there.

Comment: Logically, I guess you'll have to check if there is a connection between the top water tiles somewhere in the world, but the iteration could take a while (imagine a whole map is a giant maze with a few tiles of water in it). Ask yourself: is this real world mechanic really necessary in your video game?

Comment: I want to make the game as real as possible. I tried my hardest and came as close as I could but it's not good enough.